# GoogleToolboxForMac.framework and GoogleOpenSource.framework conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-tag-manager

I already using GoogleOpenSource.framework in my app for Google+ integration. Now I want to add Firebase Analytics with Google Tag Manager. In order to do that, It needs to include GoogleToolboxForMac.framework. Now my contains both GoogleToolboxForMac and GoogleOpenSource frameworks. 
Issue is both frameworks has GTMLogger class, so the project cannot compile. It gives

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter
```

I try to remove the GTMLogger class from one of the framework, but It cannot be done. What should be I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? i am also facing same issue.

Comment: Latest firebase with gtm integration (cocoa pods) does not needs to include GoogleToolboxForMac framework. So, it solve my issue. You may check the latest sdk

Comment: Latest firebase 4.8.2 still having issues @sajaz

Answer (score 2):

this answer those who use manual integration for adding the Firebase,

I also faced the same issue, both google+ and Firebase analytics has same file `GTMLogger` we can't remove it from the framework, instead, we need to review the Google plus integration [see this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)`Step 2.(in point 4) Initialize the Google+ Client` in they have mentioned `If your project already includes some of the open source files, you can instead include the remaining files from the OpenSource folder.` this did the trick.

since  `GTMLogger` is present in the `GoogleToolboxForMac.framework` we don't need to add this, so remove the framework of Google plus's  `GoogleOpenSource.framework` and add the files in `open source` and do not include the file `GTMLogger.m` and `GTMLogger.h` of newly downloaded `google+` frameworks folder, and remove all `imports` of this frame work, this might give some error like in the line

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]; //error
```

simply `command click` on `kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin` and import the `.h` file that is `#import "GTLPlusConstants.h"`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think its the best answer. Worked for me.